# Le « hou » onomatopéique et exclamatif : précisions sur certains emplois, adéquations ?

Tags: étymologie, zoologie, exclamations, onomatopées

> — Robins : Hou ! hou !
>  — Marions : Dieus ! Ch'est il qui la
>   hue ! / Robin, dous ami, comment vait ?
>
> [ [*Jeu de Robin et Marion*](https://archive.org/stream/lejeuderobinetma00adam#page/76/mode/2up), [Adam de La Halle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Jeu_de_Robin_et_Marion), 13<sup>e</sup> s.
>   ([manuscrit](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b6000327c/f292.item) col. 2, l. 9) ]

Au *TLFi*, on a le [*hou*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hou), mot invariable, « [s'employant] redoublé, sous forme d'un cri lancé généralement à tue-tête, pour signaler sa présence à quelqu'un » (incidemment *DHLF/Rey* dit que l'appel *hou ! hou !* est une variante de *ho !* ; et *ho !* [vient](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ho) quant à lui de *halte !*) ; d'origine onomatopéique, et qui n'est pas sans rappeler l'interjection [*coucou*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/coucou/19706?q=coucou#19591) (voir [aussi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coucou)). Mais on l'a aussi non redoublé pour le « cri lancé à quelqu'un qui passe à proximité pour le surprendre et lui faire peur », et on remarque de plus que « dans les jeux d'enfants, *hou* note le cri conventionnellement attribué au loup. Cf. *hou! le loup!* ». Par ailleurs l'onomatopée [*hou(-)hou*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hou/1) « représente un cri dont le type est celui des rapaces nocturnes », comme le [*chat-huant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chat-huant) (hibou) ou le *coucou d'Afrique*, tous deux des [*houhous*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/houhou). On atteste *houhou* en 1582 pour le cri du hibou (et la [*vieille sorcière*](http://www.littre.org/definition/houhou), aussi au 16<sup>e</sup> ; voir aussi [ici](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/6467)), puis il y a moins d'un siècle on trouve néanmoins :

> Et observant le temps que panche vers sa couche
>  Le soleil
>   abbaissé, son nocturne hou, hou
>  Du baut d'un toit chaumeux,
>   n'entonne le Hibou.
>
> [ Virgile, [*Georgiques*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9orgiques) (I, l. 403), [traduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=SQxwDb0TUNcC&dq=d'aigneaux%20virgile%20eneide&hl=fr&pg=PT139#v=onepage&q=hou&f=false) du [chevalier
>   d'Aigneaux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famille_d%27Aigneaux) (1582) ]
>
> ---
>
> Un chat-huant se mit à ululer lentement, longuement... Hoho-hô!...
>   Hoho-hô!
>
> [ Pesquidoux, *Chez nous*, 1921, p. 186 ]
>
> Pas un bruit en ce coin désert; puis tout soudain, faisant croire au
>   pistolet qu'arme un homme en embuscade, le craquement d'une pomme de
>   pin qui s'ouvre. Ou bien l'appel d'un grand-duc — ho, ho, ho ! — tel
>   qu'on se retourne, prêt à jurer que quelqu'un vous hèle.
>
> [ Pourrat, [Gaspard des montagnes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaspard_des_montagnes), 1922-1931, p.236 ]

Il ne s'agit pas d'une référence au [père Noël](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ho_ho_ho) de variété nord-américaine. Quant à [*(h)ululer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ululer), c'est un emprunt au latin pour « hurler (des chiens, des loups) », et [*huer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/huer) (possiblement basé sur l'onomatopée [hu(e)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hue), quand on veut faire avancer le cheval) lui est un peu antérieur, et réfère au cri poussé pour faire sortir un animal d'un terrier (orig. à un chien, un peu comme *(h)ululer*). *Huer* signifie aussi en emploi intransitif pousser son cri pour certains oiseaux (comme la chouette et le hibou). On sait enfin fort bien que [*se faire huer*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/huer/40570?q=huer#40478) implique de recevoir des [*huées*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hu%C3%A9e), généralement des cris...

---

- Quelle est(sont) l'(les) onomatopée(s) utilisée(s) dans les **huées** (lors d'une
  assemblée, d'un spectacle etc.) par des êtres humains ; à quoi réfère(nt)-elle(s) ?
- **Comment marque-t-on** à l'écrit la différence entre l'onomatopée ou le mot
  servant à reproduire le son du *loup*, celui imitant le cri du *rapace
  nocturne* et du *cri servant à surprendre* ; connaît-on une autre
  onomatopée pour ce dernier cri ?
- Quelle (séquence d') onomatopée(s) (avec quelle orthographe/ponctuation) représente couramment le cri du
  **rapace nocturne** comme le hibou/la chouette aujourd'hui ?
- Quelle est l'onomatopée servant à reproduire le bruit du **fantôme** ; pourquoi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je vais tâcher de répondre à ta question, mais garde à l'esprit que tu cites des ouvrages très vieux, et que les onomatopées ne sont pas fixés, bien au contraire. Ce n'est pas une science exacte.

- Pour les huées je pense que "bouh" est le terme actuel, on doit aussi pouvoir trouver "ouh"
- On a pas besoin de marquer une différence, on écrit souvent l'onomatopée comme on pense qu'il représente le mieux le son (maintenant comme au 18e siecle), et le contexte fait le reste. Pour surprendre le plus courant est "bouh", pour le loup on retrouve parfois "aouuuh".
- La chouette fait "hou" ou bien "hou-hou"
- Le bruit du fantôme est "ouh" (souvent allongé, "ouuuh"), mais je ne saurais te dire pourquoi. Je ne pense pas que les auteurs du 13e siècle écrivaient l’onomatopée des fantômes.

Concernant les orthographes du 13e siècle, comment dire.... Tu n'auras jamais à les écrire comme ça, et tant que tu les comprends quand tu les lis tu n'a pas besoin de les connaître à l'avance. Je te conseille également d'éviter de les utiliser à l'écrit dans un contexte sérieux, dans le cas contraire écris-les comme bon te semble !

Comment: Merci ! On retient que les onomatopées peuvent évoluer ? Pourquoi a-t-on aussi _bouh_ pour les huées et la surprise aujourd'hui, pourquoi pas avec une autre consonne que _b_ ? C'est le [_bubulo_](http://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1659/425) en latin ? Si j'entends aussi [ʃu] pour les huées, c'est toujours la chouette ou c'est le lancer figuratif du légume ? Je remarque que vous choisissez une orthographe différente dans chaque cas; est-ce une seule onomatopée qu'on fait varier ou différents trucs qui se ressemblent ? Le fantôme c'est le vent ; le vent c'est le hou aussi ?? Il a quoi ce [u] ?

Comment: Oui elles peuvent évoluer, d'ailleurs ça nous fait bien rigoler de lire des onomatopées dans la vieille littérature ! Pour la surprise je parle du fait d'essayer de faire peur à quelqu'un. Je ne saurais te dire pourquoi, tant que c'est pareil en anglais (= dans d'autres langues) ça me paraît "naturel"... Je n'ai jamais entendu [ʃu] pour les huées personnellement. Pour l'orthographe, je dirais qu'on met presque systématiquement un 'h' aux onomatopées, devant si le son est plus brusque (même si on ne le prononce pas), et à la fin sinon. Je dirais que c'est des trucs qui se ressemblent, pas 1/2

Comment: des variations de la même onomatopée. Pour le vent je ne sais honnêtement pas, tu trouvera surement des "ouuh" ou des variations. Et je n'ai pas compris ta dernière question. 2/2

Comment: Merci ! Je voulais dire il a quoi de particulier ce son [u] (qui fait qu'on le retrouve à toutes ces sauces) mais votre commentaire à l'effet que ce serait plutôt des trucs distincts qui se ressemblent y répond indirectement.

Comment: Oui, on a tendance à regrouper les choses qui se ressembles même si il n'y a pas forcément de règle générale ou d'héritage particulier ^^